# Significato di "pesar giú" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Ma il mio amore è Paco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> – Cosa fai al pozzo? Paco, cosa fai? Vieni subito via! 
>         – Addio, Giulia, – disse semplicemente mio zio. 
>         – Ma che fai? Non vorrai…? 
>         Accennò di sí con la testa e prese a farsi **pesar giú**.

La mia domanda è sul senso di questo "pesar giú" che appare nel brano sopra citato. Ho cercato alla voce "pesare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho saputo trovare il significato di questa espressione. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Si è per caso gettato nel pozzo a peso morto?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Non si è finalmente gettato, ma aveva l'intenzione di farlo.

Comment: Ho l'impressione che significhi sporgersi nel vuoto in maniera pericolosa. Voleva gettarsi in un pozzo dopo aver perso tutto al gioco.

Comment: @abarisone: Sporgersi in modo che il suo peso cominciasse a farlo andare giù. Ha senso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ho l'impressione che significhi sporgersi nel vuoto del pozzo in maniera pericolosa.

Voleva gettarsi nel pozzo dopo aver perso tutto al gioco e si era messo in una posizione tale che il suo stesso peso lo facesse piano piano scivolare e poi precipitare giù.

Comment: non sono molto d'accordo sul "piano piano". Se ti sporgi e cadi, il tuo peso ti trascina giù di colpo :)

Comment: Ho riformulato. Vero è che il fatto di essere indeciso sul gesto da compiere non contemplerebbe un gesto fulmineo ed improvviso.

Comment: ok :) grazie, ottimo.